# `Fetch` API inside a Typescript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

I am using `isomorphic-fetch` package inside a typescript class and trying to identify how I can return the value of the fetch api response.

```
somefunction(someParam: Int): Int {
  fetch('myApiURL', { method: 'get'})
    .then(function(res) {
       return res
    })
    .catch(function(ex) {
       return 0
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a *value* like `Int` because JavaScript is single threaded and the function cannot hold the thread *hostage* till it returns. However you can return a Promise, that is what `fetch` returns anyways so:

```
somefunction(someParam: number): Promise<number> {
  return fetch('myApiURL', { method: 'get'})
    .then(function(res) {
       return res
    })
    .catch(function(ex) {
       return 0
    })
}
```

PS: there is no int. Just `number` in JavaScript / TypeScript :)

Comment: thanks basarat. In that case how can I unwrap the promise and get the value.

Comment: Chain with a `then` `somefunction(123).then(val=>{/*use val*/});`. More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/promise.html